# IntelliJ Not Highlighing Anything

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I create a new Java project or open an existing one, IntelliJ doesn’t highlight any of the text nor does it suggest anything. All the code is 1 single color. I’ve marked my src file, made sure power safe is off, made sure highlight is enabled, and even reinstalled IntelliJ CE. I’ve also disabled all plugins. Any suggestions is appreciated.

[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7WVM.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your entire window?

Comment: Is your source file ending with `.java` suffix?

Comment: Please make sure that the .java extension is listed in "Registered patterns" for the Java file type in Settings | Editor | File Types.

Comment: added a picture for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that the file is not recognized as a java source file.

Go to `Preferences -> Editor -> File types`

Scroll down in the list of `Recognized File Types` and click `Java`.
In the list of registered patterns make sure it shows `*.java`.

Also ensure the file is not marked in the `Ignore files and folders` section at the bottom of this preferences panel. Perhaps you added it by accident (with some shortcut).

Also, while reinstalling IntelliJ, you have probably imported your previous settings. With it, you inherited this issue.

If this doesn't help, please share a screenshot of your project/module structure and setup.

Last but not least, try to create the file using the context menu. E.g. try to right click on your src folder and select `new` and select Java class or Package from the options. Would be good to check anyway, to see if these are valid options. If they do not appear here, it indicates the project setup is erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks to @yole I did the following 'make sure that the *.java extension is listed in "Registered patterns" for the Java file type in Settings | Editor | File Types".

Comment: I'm not expecting a response, by why in the world _wasn't_ it.  I can't remember when I first set up IntelliJ, but I'd be very shocked if the default setting wasn't to have `.java` files recognised as java files...

Comment: I've must've messed around with some of the settings because it worked when I first downloaded it.